# Link within the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am linking the table of content with the heading of a section in the same page. However, when the screen scrolls down to the desired section the actual linked heading gets lost under the navigation bar which is kept as fixed. It is working fine on the mobile preview. Having issue with the desktop. Following is the code i am using :

```
<div class="content uk-width-1-2@l uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@s">
  <span class="anchor" id="Overview"></span>
  <h2>Overview</h2>
  <p> As a very high-level summary:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Companu has strong application, network and infrastructure-level
      security controls in place to ensure your data is safely stored
      and processed <br /><br />
    </li>
    <li>
      Company serves multiple tenants from the same application codebase,
      but uses effective isolation techniques to keep tenant data separate
      <br /><br />
    </li>
    <li>
      Privacy laws, which are broadly compatible with many other jurisdictions
      (for example, we support the rights of access and rectification
      for data subjects) <br/><br/>
    </li>
    <li>Comapny is hosted on AWS, in multiple regions, using VPC <br /><br /></li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    You'll find more information on each of these points
    in the detailed chapters documents below.
  </p>
</div>

.anchor {
  display: block;
  height: 63px;
  /* this is the height of your header */
  margin-top: -63px;
  /* this is again negative value of the height of your header */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Can anyone please help to sort this problem.

Comment: So when you click the link it scrolls past the heading and only displays the content below it? Is this the issue?

Comment: @LoveHateDevelopment yeah

Comment: There's not enough code here to determine a solution. You have to learn HTML and CSS. A `<span>` that is `display:block;`? That's what `<div>`s are for.

Comment: @PHPglue - This is a very good point. Spans are constantly misused.

Comment: Browsers will position the linked element at the top of the viewport. This is the default behavior. You can use JavaScript to override this behavior by listening for a click event on links with a fragment URL.

Comment: @PHPglue thanks for the response. This span was used to complement the height of the nav bar. Can you please suggest a better solution please.

Comment: Yeah, just use a `<div>`, as `<span>`s that are not `display:block;` can't have a height.

Comment: @PHPglue thanks. However, its still not overriding the behaviour

Comment: You have to change the `<span>` to a `<div>` in the HTML, and adjust the corresponding CSS selector as well. In time.. you will learn.

Comment: So . hav done this and apply the same css classes to the this section too<div class="anchor" id="Overview"></div>

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to add an invisible pseudo element to the original target element of the links via CSS, like this:

```
#Overview::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -63px; 
  height: 63px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

This will "extend" the element with that ID in a way which causes the anchor to be 63px above the main element (can be any value), without causing any other visible changes.

Note: I would assign the `Overview` ID directly to the `h2` element, not to an extra `span`

Here it is in a snippet example:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #d75;
}

.something_in_between {
  height: 500px;
  background: #75f;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

#Overview {
  background: yellow;
  height: 500px;
}

#Overview::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -63px;
  height: 63px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Fixed Header</div>
<div class="something_in_between">Here's the <a href="#Overview">LINK</a> to the "Overview" element</div>
<div id="Overview">This should be visible when clicking the link</div>
```